# Deserialise XML Documents to .NET Objects with types from dynamically loaded assemblies

Tags: .net, xml

I'm working on a project whereby I have a series of configuration classes in a core assembly and I want to enable users to be able to create the instances of config objects by creating XML documents.

For this I'm thinking of creating xsd files for the base classes.

My next problem is that I have some assemblies that are loaded dynamically and not know at design time.  They'd all implement a common set of interfaces.

The big question is how could I create a object graph instantiating nested types from dynamically loaded assemblies?

E.g.

```
<mycoreobject>
  <somethings>
  <ass1:plugintype1 att="aaa"/> //implementing ISomthing from dynamically loaded assembly
  </somethings>
</mycoreobject>
```

The end result I'd want a core mycoreobject object with a list of ISomethings which are actually instantiated as the types from their respective assemblies.

In XAML we do something similar by defining the namespaces, each referring to a specific assembly. Where in the case of my example ass1 would be an alias for the externals assembly.

The more I'm writing this, the more I'm assuming I'm just going to have to analyse the XML content and construct the object graph manually?

Any tips, ideas or solutions welcome.

Tia

Sam

Comment: You can specify subclasses to XmlSerializer at runtime via the constructors that take either Type[] (extraTypes), or XmlAttributeOverrides (adding XmlIncludeAttribute instances)

Comment: So is it possible to Deserialise elements with namespace tags referencing specific types. I.e could you say myns:mytype deserialises as DynamicallyLoadedAssmebly.MyType?

Comment: yes it is; added example for both read and write. Note that the namespace aliases (`ass1`) must still be formally declared in an `xmlns:ass1="..."`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like so?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
public class MyBase
{
}
public class ConcreteType : MyBase
{
    [XmlAttribute("att")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
[XmlRoot("mycoreobject")]
public class SomeRoot
{
    public List<MyBase> Items { get; set; }
}
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        XmlAttributeOverrides xao = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
        XmlAttributes extraTypes = new XmlAttributes();
        extraTypes.XmlArray = new XmlArrayAttribute("somethings");
        // assume loaded dynamically, along with name/namespace
        extraTypes.XmlArrayItems.Add(new XmlArrayItemAttribute("plugintype1",
            typeof(ConcreteType)) { Namespace = "my-plugin-namespace" });
        xao.Add(typeof(SomeRoot), "Items", extraTypes);

        // important: need to cache and re-use "ser", or will leak assemblies
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SomeRoot), xao);

        //example 1: writing
        var obj = new SomeRoot { Items = new List<MyBase> { new ConcreteType { Value = "abc" } } };
        XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("", "");
        ns.Add("ass1", "my-plugin-namespace");
        ser.Serialize(Console.Out, obj, ns);

        // example 2: reading
        string xml = @"<mycoreobject xmlns:ass1=""my-plugin-namespace"">
  <somethings>
  <ass1:plugintype1 att=""aaa""/>
  </somethings>
</mycoreobject>";

        obj = (SomeRoot)ser.Deserialize(new StringReader(xml));
        var foundIt = (ConcreteType)obj.Items.Single();
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine(foundIt.Value); // should be "aaa"       
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent example Marc. Definitely the answer I was looking for with a sample!! Thank you.  Is there a way I could incorporate plugin xsds to enable an XML editor to use a schema, again like vs does for XAML?

Comment: @sambomartin what editor are you using / thinking of using? That is pretty key. For example, VS allows this (there's a folder you just drop plugin xsd into), but you can't simply give VS to your end-users.

Comment: I suppose in real terms I'd leave that down to implementation. Ive got no desire to write an XML editor and Would prefer to offer a proper ui rather than an editor. The xsds could be generated at run time from the objects though, so in theory I could allow for using any XML editors, xmlpad etc. I know about the vs XML scheme create tool xsd.exe, you know of anything build into framework or .net component that could do this?

Comment: I'm having problem using your example when using an interface in the items.  In reality I have the base and concrete class both implement IMyBase and IConcreteType, some root holds a List<IMyBase>  is this still achievable.  Im getting cannot serialise exception because it's an interface.  Do i need to look at implementing IXMLSerliazer? thanks again